# Is it a good practise to store special characters in database as html escape equivalent character eg. & as &amp;

Tags: sql, database-design

I am not using standard parser to read input xml.

Input xml is having `&`,`<`,`>` special characters and I want to store them after converting them to html escape charcters as `&amp;` , `&gt;` in database.

This is required because I want to display the same ie. in format `&amp;` in my output xml for other client.

Comment: No. Store the data as-is. Format or encode it when displaying.

Comment: I agree with Salman. You should format the values when you _display_ them, not when you store them.

Answer (score 2):

No. What if you have a later requirement for JSON output, or something else that *isn't* HTML or XML? Now you need to undo the HTML escaping first and then perform whatever escaping *is* appropriate for the new medium.

Databases should store *data*. Leave presentation concerns to applications, services or reporting tools which know *what format is required* for each use case (and may even have to make decisions on a per-request basis, such as a REST service using content negotiation)

---

> I am not using standard parser to read input xml.

That's also a really bad plan. People who ignore standard tools and write their own frequently make mistakes. If you're writing your own, have you actually *read* the full [spec for XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/)? Do you properly understand namespaces (A frequent source of errors in my experience)?